# Self-referential struct defined in a C header file produces error

Tags: c, struct, c-preprocessor, header-files, user-defined-data-types

I am trying to write a header file containing macros for a generic type doubly linked list.

The nodes are defined as follows:

```
#define node(T)                \
    struct node_##T            \
    {                          \
        T val;                 \
        struct node_##T *next; \
        struct node_##T *prev; \
    }
```

I am then using `node(T)` to create a `linkedlist(T)` struct:

```
#define linkedlist(T)       \
    struct linkedlist_##T   \
    {                       \
        unsigned int count; \
        node(T) *head;      \
        node(T) *end;       \
    }
```

Finally, a `linkedlist(Student) ll;` is declared, which calls `node(Student)` and produces this error at compilation:

```
error: redefinition of ‘struct node_Student’
```

The error occurs at the line at which `struct node_##T` is first declared.

Interestingly, the error goes away when I insert a semicolon at the end of the struct definition like this:

```
        . . . .
        struct node_##T *prev; \
    };
```

However, this cannot be done as then the declaration `node(T) N;` would be impossible.

What could be a possible fix?

Comment: Note `struct node_##T` will not work well when `T` is `long long`.

Comment: Interesting.... trying to implement C++ templates with C macros. Maybe you should upgrade to C++ !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler is completely correct. You are redeclaring your struct. Change the linked list definition to say

```
#define linkedlist(T)       \
    struct linkedlist_##T   \
    {                       \
        unsigned int count; \
        struct node_##T *head;     \
        struct node_##T *end;      \
    };
```

instead. You'll need to have a separate `node(T)` line for each `T` before `linkedlist(T)` somewhere.

Comment: You'll still get a redefinition if you try to declare multiple variables using `linkedlist(T)`.

Comment: Would an `#if` / `#endif` guard help?

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I understand where the error lies. However, linkedlist(T) is used as a type, so adding `node(T);` to the definition is not possible. I just edited the question to clarify that.

Comment: Then simply do a `node(T)` outside of that macro itself. You only need to do that once in your code.